# Intellij not displaying file when clicking on it in project view

Tags: intellij-idea

When I click on a file in the project view, it shows me a dropdown listing all the methods in the file.

[image]

I don't want that - I just want it to display the file on the main window.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the `Project` title bar or click `Show Options Menu` cog, and deselect [`Show Members`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-tool-window.html#show_members):

> If this option is on, the files in the tree that contain classes turn
>   into nodes. When such node is unfolded, the contained classes with
>   their fields, methods, and other members of the selected item are
>   shown.

[image]